# Python Unit test how to test a method which calls another method

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, python-unittest

I'm using python's built-in unit test tool: `unittest`

```
class MyClass:
  def a():
    # some operations
    self.spark = SparkSession.builder.config(xxxx).getOrCreate()
```

How can I test this method?

Since `a()` calls SparkSession method directly.
How am I going to test it?

Comment: Any code that creates new instances us hard to test because you cannot pass in test dummies. Consider passing `spark` to `a`. If you don't want to change the interface, make it at least an optional argument which defaults to what it is using now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unittest.mock.patch` to patch out `SparkSession`.  Here's a self-contained single-file example that follows your example code as closely as possible and produces a passing `pytest` result:

```
SparkSession = None

class MyClass:
    def a(self):
        # some operations
        self.spark = SparkSession.builder.config('xxxx').getOrCreate()


from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('test.SparkSession')
def test_myclass_a(mock_spark_session):
    MyClass().a()
```

Note that if I didn't patch `SparkSession` out, calling `MyClass().a()` would raise an `AttributeError` since `SparkSession` is otherwise `None`.

`MyClass` is defined in a file I created called `test.py` so I patched `'test.SparkSession'`; you should patch it in the module under test, not the test module.

Comment: I guess I need to create a `mock_spark_session`, right? I did so and I got an error: `RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number` but I do have Java in my env path variable

Comment: Nope, `patch` creates it for you (as a `unittest.mock.Mock` object) and passes it as an argument to the test function.  That's why `a()` doesn't raise an exception in my test, `SparkSession` has been replaced with a `Mock` object so it automagically has any attribute that's requested and doesn't touch the "real" `SparkSession"`.  If you got an error, it means you didn't patch `SparkSession` correctly.

Comment: thanks for explanation. how does `unittest.mock.Mock` know what methods and properties in the real `SparkSession` which it needs to mock?

Comment: just to confirm that the `SparkSession` created by the `patch()` will be named `mock_spark_session` right? so I can name it with whatever name, correct?

Comment: how about a fixture who has the same name `mock_spark_session`? In this case, will the `patch()` created spark session overrides the fixture created spark session?

Comment: You're way overthinking this.  :)  Just read the doc on `patch` and `Mock`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch  `@patch` replaces the patched symbol with a `Mock` object (for the duration of the decorated function) and passes it as an argument to the function.  Obviously you can name a function parameter anything you like.  `Mock` objects mock all their attributes with more `Mock`s.

Comment: Note that I gave you a fully working example that you can run and play with.  If you're not able to get from there to the thing you actually need to test, you probably should have included more detail in the example you provided as part of your question...